# Compare Values Across Different Sheets (VBA/Formulas)

Tags: excel, vba, for-loop

I have two excel sheets, one cumulative (year-to-date) and one periodic (quarterly). I am trying to check for potential entry errors.

Simplified ytd table:

```
ID      Q1/18       Q2/18        Q3/18      Q4/18      Q1/19     Q2/19     ...
1        6           12            20        28        10        20       
2        5           11            18        26        10        20       
3        5           11            18        26        10        20
```

Simplified quarterly table:

```
ID     Q1/18       Q2/18        Q3/18      Q4/18      Q1/19     Q2/19     ...
1        6           6            8          8         10        10       
2        5           6            7          8         10        10       
3        5           6            7          8         10        10
```

In the above example there are no entry errors.

I am trying to create a third sheet that would look something like this

```
ID     Q1/18       Q2/18        Q3/18      Q4/18      Q1/19     Q2/19     ...
1                    T            T          T         T        T       
2                    T            T          T         T        T       
3                    T            T          T         T        T
```

I initially tried using a formula like this:

```
 =IF('YTD'!C2-'YTD LC'!B2-'QTR'!B2=0,T,F)
```

I don't particularly like this because the formula will not apply in the first quarter. This also assumes that my data in both sheets are ordered in the same way. Whilst I believe it to be true in all cases, I would rather have something like an index-match to confirm.

I tried working on a VBA solution based on other solutions I found here but made less progress than via the formulas:

```
Sub Compare()

lrow = Cells (Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
lcol = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xltoLeft).Column

Sheets.Add
ActiveSheet.Name = "Temp Sheet"

For i = 2 To lrow
    For j = 3 To lcol

    valytd = Worksheets("YTD").Cells(i,j).Value
    valytd = Worksheets("YTD").Cells(i,j).Value

    If valytd = valytd Then
        Worksheets("Temp").Cells(i,j).Value = "T"
    Else:                           
        Worksheets("Temp").Cells(i,j).Value = "F"
        Worksheets("Temp").Cells(i,j).Interior.Color Index = 40

    End If
    Next j
 Next i
 End Sub
```

Comment: Is your data sample large or like this a few rows?

Comment: It's pretty large.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick, the code is all commented:

```
Option Explicit
Sub Compare()

    Dim arrYTD As Variant, arrQuarterly As Variant, arrResult As Variant
    Dim Compare As Scripting.Dictionary 'You need Microsoft Scripting Runtime for this to work
    Dim i As Long, j As Integer, x As Integer

    With Application
        .EnableEvents = False
        .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
        .DisplayAlerts = False
        .ScreenUpdating = False
    End With

    With ThisWorkbook
        arrYTD = .Sheets("Name of YTD sheet").UsedRange.Value 'this will get everything on that sheet
        arrQuarterly = .Sheets("Name of Quarterly sheet").UsedRange.Value 'this will get everything on that sheet
    End With
    ReDim arrResult(1 To UBound(arrYTD), 1 To UBound(arrYTD, 2)) 'resize the final array with the same size of YTD

    Set Compare = New Scripting.Dictionary

    'Here we fill the dictionary with the ID's position on the arrQuarterly array
    For i = 2 To UBound(arrQuarterly) '2 because 1 is headers
        If Not Compare.Exists(arrQuarterly(i, 1)) Then 'this is an error handle if you have duplicated ID's
            Compare.Add arrQuarterly(i, 1), i 'now we know the position of that ID on the table
        Else
            'Your handle if there was a duplicated ID
        End If
    Next i

    'Let's fill the headers on the result array
    For i = 1 To UBound(arrYTD, 2)
        arrResult(1, i) = arrYTD(1, i)
    Next i

    'Now let's compare both tables assuming the columns are the same on both tables (same position)
    For i = 1 To UBound(arrYTD)
        arrResult(i, 1) = arrYTD(i, 1) 'This is the ID
        For j = 2 To UBound(arrYTD, 2)
            x = Compare(arrYTD(i, 1)) 'this way we get the position on the quarterly array for that ID
            If arrYTD(i, j) = arrQuarterly(x, j) Then 'compare if they have the same value on both sides
                arrResult(i, j) = "T"
            Else
                arrResult(i, j) = "F"
            End If
        Next j
    Next i

    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Name of the result sheet") 'paste the array to it's sheet
        .Range("A1", .Cells(UBound(arrResult), UBound(arrResult, 2))).Value = arrResult
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for this. However I get an error in the line: If Not Compare.Exists(arrQuarterly(i, 1)) Then I'm not too familiar with what "Compare" is doing here and so am struggling to edit the code. Would appreciate if you could share!

Edit: The tick box for Microsoft Scripting Runtime is checked.

Comment: @Cheryl sorry I always forget to initialize the dictionary, I've edited my answer now it should work. `Compare` is the dictionary here if you want to learn about dictionaries you can read [this](http://www.snb-vba.eu/VBA_Dictionary_en.html)

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion the easiest way is to:

1. Create a sheet & copy paste row 1 + Column 1 like image below (Title & IDs)
2. Use Sum Product to get your answers

**Formula:**

```
=IF(SUMPRODUCT((Sheet1!$B$1:$G$1=Sheet3!$B$1)*(Sheet1!$A$2:$A$4=Sheet3!A2)*(Sheet1!$B$2:$G$4))=SUMPRODUCT((Sheet2!$B$1:$G$1=Sheet3!$B$1)*(Sheet2!$A$2:$A$4=Sheet3!A2)*(Sheet2!$B$2:$G$4)),"T","F")
```

**Formula Notes:**

- Keep fix the range with Quarters using double $$ -> Sheet1!$B$1:$G$1
- keep fix the range with IDs using double $$ -> Sheet1!$A$2:$A$4
- Keep fix the range with values -> Sheet1!$B$2:$G$
- Keep fix column header -> =Sheet3!$B$1
- Leave variable rows number -> =Sheet3!A2

**Images:**

[image]

Comment: Hi can you explain how the double $$ will prevent the problem with the quarterly results?

Comment: Using $$ you make the range you target fix. So if you want to drag down your formula and the specific range to remain the same you must use $$.